# The ten commandments ,are the five first and the five last connected:1-6,2-7,3-8 and so on?

Tags: theology, aseres-hadibros

The ten commandments ,are the five first and the five last connected?

Rabbi Mordechai Kraft teaches that the sages(I have no source)did teach that 
the first five commandments works together with the five last.

Example:

1) I am the Lord thy god, who brought thee out of the land of Egypt, out of the house of bondage.

6) Thou shalt not murder.

(Rabbi: He explains that if you murder,you murder the image of Hashem("your killing Hashem")

If there is a connection,where can we find the source for this in the Torah,Talmud?

Can someone explain the connection:1-6,2-7 and so on?

Comment: About 3 decades ago I gave a Shavu'oth-night (early morning) Drasha on the parallel between the 1st 5 and the 2nd 5. I don't have time to find you sources right now, but I can still explain how the 5 sets match up, if you want.

Comment: @DannySchoemann Thank you,that would be great.Its the number 5 and 10 I dont really understand . And how this knowledge came to life.

Comment: Done. The Mechilta already matched them up, and the Kli Yakar brings it and sometimes adds something.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Kli Yakar on the last verse (20:13) explains it nicely. He brings the Mechilta and then sometimes adds his own thoughts.

Here's a brief summary (with some possible additions). The original is below.

**1. I am the Lord your Gcd <-> 6. Murder**

As humans are created in the image of Gcd, killing a person diminishes the godliness in this world. (Besides for the murderer *playing Gcd* by deciding who gets to live/die.)

It's also a reminder that Esav didn't receive the Torah because they live *on their sword*; belief in Gcd and belief in one's own power don't go together.

**2. Do not have any other gods <-> 7. Adultery**

Adultery: *Using* someone else's spouse, the way the idol worshiper worships a partner along with Gcd. (Besides for the adulterer profaning the sanctity of marriage.)

Also, throughout Tanach we see adultery is used as an idiom for idolatry.

**3. Name in vain <-> 8. Stealing**

Taking something that you shouldn't. (Besides for the thief will have to make a false oath to cover himself.)

Also, both these involve the concept that *Gcd isn't watching me when I sin*.

**4. Shabbat <-> 9. False witness**

Shabbat observation declares our belief that Gcd created the world in 6 days and rested on the 7th. Desecrating Shabbat makes us a false witness - or destroys the ability to be a good witness.

Also, proper Shabbat observance involves only talking Shabbat-permitted talk; highlighting the concept of *sanctifying speech*. False testimony is prevented when realising that speech needs to be sanctified.

**5. Honouring parents <-> 10. Coveting**

By following through with the *coveting* of another's wife, you create situations whereby it becomes impossible to honour one's parents, and the kid will never know who its father is.

Also, somebody who covets other's money can't honour his parents properly, as his entire life is focused on *more money*, leaving no time or energy for honouring parents.

> לא תרצח לא תנאף וגו'. אחר שהשלים ה' דברות שבין אדם למקום ברוך הוא הזכיר כנגדם ה' דברות שבין אדם לחבירו כדרך שנזכרו במכילתא איך היו מקבילים זה לעומת זה והדמיונות ההם כי מה שאמרו לא תרצח כנגד אנכי, כי כל מי ששופך דמים כאילו ממעט הצלם והדמות שנאמר (בראשית ט.ו) שופך דם האדם באדם דמו ישפך כי בצלם אלהים עשה את האדם. ואין צורך לטעם זה כי אם לאומר הרגני נא הרוג ומוחל לו ההריגה ואעפ"כ דמו ישפך כי לא ניתן למחילה בעבור שיש בו חלק אלוה ממעל וחלק גבוה מי יתיר וזהו הטעם גם בהורג עצמו.‏
>
> וענין הצלם והדמות הוא, שבכל המראות דרכו ית' להתראות בדמיון צלם האדם אע"פ שבלי ספק אין שם צלם ודמות כביכול כמ"ש (ישעיה מ.כה) ואל מי תדמיוני ואשוה יאמר קדוש. וכתיב מה דמות תערכו לו, (שם מ.יח) מ"מ כשהוא מתראה אז הוא מראה דמות אדם לבריות ובעבור חשיבתו של האדם הוא מתראה בדמיון זה כמ"ש (יחזקאל א.כו) ועל הכסא דמות כמראה אדם, הנך רואה שבאמת לא היה שם מראה אדם אלא דמות כמראה אדם וכן נראה על הים כגבור ועל הר סיני כזקן, ולפיכך ראוי לנהוג כבוד באותו דמות והרוצח ממעט הדמות כי הוא גורם שאין הקב"ה ירצה עוד להתראות בדמיון זה מאחר שהוא בזוי על הבריות והרואה הנרצח הוא דוגמת כי קללת אלהים תלוי ואין להאריך עוד מזה. ‏
>
> ולי נראה לומר לכך בא דבור **לא תרצח, כנגד אנכי**, לפי שיעקב ועשו עשו חלוקה ביניהם כי יעקב בחר לו יה לחלקו וה' מנת חלקו ועשו בחר לו אומנות על חרבך תחיה וע"כ כפר בעיקר כדמסיק (בב"ב טז:) שכפר בעיקר מדכתיב למה זה לי וכתיב זה אלי וגו'. ולפיכך בא ציווי אנכי לבית יעקב, וכנגד זה הזהירם שלא יאחזו באומנות עשו כי אומנות זה הביאו לידי כפירה ומטעם לא תרצח לא קבלו בני עשו התורה כי הרציחה מביאו לידי כפירה באנכי ה' אלהיך וא"כ בטלה כל התורה כ"א אין מצוה אין מקום לשום ציווי וע"כ לא רצה לקבל אפילו שאר הדברות כי ענין הרציחה סותר הכל, כי הרוצח חושב שהוא עושה רצון מזל מאדים בכח השר של מעלה ובזה הוא מכחיש אלהותו ית' ואלו דברים עתיקים. ‏
>
> **לא יהיה לך אלהים אחרים, כנגדו לא תנאף**. כמ"ש בעובדי ע"ז האשה המנאפת וגו' (יחזקאל טז.לב) וכן רבים. ול"נ לומר שהניאוף גורם גם לעבוד ע"ז ומעשה בעל פעור בשיטים יוכיח וכמ"ש בחיתון ז' אומות כי יסיר את בנך מאחרי (דברים ז.א) כי אין לך דבר המביא לידי ע"ז כמו פיתוי אשה זרה אשר בחלק שפתיה תדיחנו מעל ה' ודבר זה ידוע ומפורסם והמפורסמות א"צ ראיה. ‏
>
> **לא תשא כנגד לא תגנוב**. כי הגונב סופו לישבע לשקר שנאמר (ויקרא יט.יא–יב) לא תגנובו וגו' ולא תשבעו וגו' כי זה גורר את זה ולכך נאמר (זכריה ה.ד) ובאה אל בית הגנב ואל בית הנשבע בשמי לשקר וכלתו וגו'. השוה ב' עבירות אלו לפי שאחת גוררת חבירתה וענינם אחד כי הגונב עושה עין של מעלה כאילו אינו רואה כביכול וכן זה הנשבע לשקר כדי לאמת שקרו בפני הבריות עושה ג"כ עין של מעלה כאילו אינו רואה כביכול, ולפיכך מאן דעביד הא נפיל בהא אף אם נשבע באיזה דבר אחר שאינו מענין גניבה כך נ"ל נוסף על מה שנזכר במכילתא. ‏
>
> **זכור את יום השבת, כנגדו לא תענה**. כי כל מחלל שבת מעיד שלא ברא הקב"ה עולמו בו' ימים ונח בז'. ול"נ לפי שנאמר בשבת ממצוא חפצך ודבר דבר (ישעיה נח.יג) וארז"ל (שבת קיג:) שלא יהא דבורך של שבת כדבורך של חול, וטעמו של דבר הוא לפי שכל פעולות האדם הוא בכלי המעשה שלו אבל פעולת הקב"ה הוא בדבור לבד כי בדבר ה' שמים נעשו, והוא אמר ויהי, (תהלים לג.ו–ט) ולפי זה כשהאדם שובת בשבת ואינו עושה מלאכה בכלי המעשה שלו אין שביתה זו דומה לשביתת הקב"ה כי הקב"ה שבת אפילו מדיבור פיו והאדם אינו שובת כ"א מפעולת כלי המעשה ע"כ נאמר ודבר דבר שלא יהא דבורך של שבת כדבורך של חול לזכור שביתת הקב"ה אשר שבת מן הדבור וממנו תראה וכן תעשה שלא לדבר בשבת מחפצך כי אם מחפצי שמים וע"י שיזכור את יום השבת שהוא מחוייב לקדש מוצא שפתיו שלא לדבר בדברי חול אז לפחות בשאר ימות השבוע אע"פ שכלי שנשתמש בו קודש בשבת ישתמש בו חול בימי השבוע מ"מ לפחות יקדש דברי שפתיו שלא להוציא שקר מפיו ולענות סרה בחבירו. ‏
>
> **כבד את אביך וגו', כנגדו לא תחמוד**. ומסיק במכילתא שכל החומד לסוף מוליד בן שמקללו ודבר זה מחוסר ביאור כי מה ענין זה לזה, ונראה לפרש לפי שכל חומד אשת רעהו ודאי הוא מהרהר בה בשעת תשמיש ודומה כאילו הבן נולד לו מאשה אחרת אשר חמד והרהר בה ע"כ אינו מכבד את אמו כראוי לפי שאביו היה מהרהר באשה אחרת, וגם את אביו לא יכבד כראוי כי החומד נשים אין כוונתו להוליד כי אם למלאות תאותו ולא נתכוין אל בן זה להולידו ע"כ דומה כאילו אינו בנו וע"כ לא יכבדו גם כן כי הכל הולך אחר הכוונה, וחמדת ממון תלוי ג"כ בכבוד אב ואם כי החומד ממון אחרים אינו מכבדם כראוי מחמת היותו להוט בפולמוס חמדת הממון כי הכיבוד הוא מהונו להאכילם ולהשקותם ולהלבישם, וזה החומד בלי ספק שעינו צרה גם באביו ואמו מלתת להם די מחסורם.  ‏

Comment: On the last point, I was told that coveting can go so far as wanting to be someone else and not yourself,  essentially wishing you had been born to other parents instead of your own.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this seem to be the idea. Idolatry (2nd) is often compared with sexual perversion(adultery) (7th). E.t.c. See Jeremiah 3:8-9

Comment: @sabbahillel but how 5 and 10 works I dunno,maybe you do?

Comment: @Eagel I remember seeing something about it and also the fact that Number 5 (honoring parents) is a connection between laws between Man and Hashem and laws between man and man. However, I do not have the details. I think that Dennis Prager had a tape about it.